# zarr consolidate_metadata errors with TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Array'

Tags: python, zarr

I'm trying to consolidate the metadata of an existing zarr store, though the same error occurs if I make a new zarr store and call `zarr.consolidate_metadata(store)`.

Code example:

```
import zarr

## create test zarr store
path_to_store = "test.zarr"
store = zarr.open(path_to_store)
store.create_dataset('foo', shape=(10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000), dtype='i4')

## call consolidate_metadata on store
zarr.consolidate_metadata(store)
```

This creates a `.zmetadata` *directory*, not a file, with a 0 chunk inside like it's a zarr array. But the call itself errors out with `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Array'`.

I think it's probably a bug in zarr that it creates this `.zmetadata` array, but I tried with different zarr and Python versions so I'm pretty sure I'm also doing something wrong because such a major bug couldn't last long.

The full error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/xf/xwjm3rj52ls9780rvrbbb9tm0000gn/T/ipykernel_84668/2011535042.py in <module>
      1 ## call consolidate_metadata on store
----> 2 zarr.consolidate_metadata(store)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/convenience.py in consolidate_metadata(store, metadata_key)
   1122     }
   1123     store[metadata_key] = json_dumps(out)
-> 1124     return open_consolidated(store, metadata_key=metadata_key)
   1125 
   1126 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/convenience.py in open_consolidated(store, metadata_key, mode, **kwargs)
   1176 
   1177     # setup metadata store
-> 1178     meta_store = ConsolidatedMetadataStore(store, metadata_key=metadata_key)
   1179 
   1180     # pass through

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/storage.py in __init__(self, store, metadata_key)
   2767 
   2768         # retrieve consolidated metadata
-> 2769         meta = json_loads(store[metadata_key])
   2770 
   2771         # check format of consolidated metadata

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zarr/util.py in json_loads(s)
     33 def json_loads(s: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
     34     """Read JSON in a consistent way."""
---> 35     return json.loads(ensure_text(s, 'ascii'))
     36 
     37 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numcodecs/compat.py in ensure_text(s, encoding)
    126 def ensure_text(s, encoding='utf-8'):
    127     if not isinstance(s, str):
--> 128         s = ensure_contiguous_ndarray(s)
    129         s = codecs.decode(s, encoding)
    130     return s

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numcodecs/compat.py in ensure_contiguous_ndarray(buf, max_buffer_size)
     79 
     80     # ensure input is a numpy array
---> 81     arr = ensure_ndarray(buf)
     82 
     83     # check for object arrays, these are just memory pointers, actual memory holding

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gefs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numcodecs/compat.py in ensure_ndarray(buf)
     43         # N.B., first take a memoryview to make sure that we subsequently create a
     44         # numpy array from a memory buffer with no copy
---> 45         mem = memoryview(buf)
     46 
     47         # instantiate array from memoryview, ensures no copy

TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Array'
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct call is:

```
zarr.consolidate_metadata(path_to_store)
```

Just pass the path, not the actual ZarrGroup you get from opening a store. This works (for me) without manual cleanup of the `.zmetadata` directory since consolidate_metadata is supposed to overwrite the existing file anyway.